# Align top of an image in \marginnote to \baseline+\height

Tags: graphics, marginnote

My document contains some info graphics in the margin.
I realise it by the `marginnote` package.
How do I align the top of an image to the top of the paragraph (`\baseline+\height`) with different factors in `\setstretch`?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% load packages
\usepackage{blindtext, setspace}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{showframe}

\renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\tiny}

\begin{document}
\raggedleft

\blindtext

\marginnote{\rule{5mm}{20mm}}
X

\blindtext

\clearpage
\setstretch{1.6}

\blindtext

\marginnote{\rule{5mm}{20mm}}
X

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

The interesting parts are the top alignment of `X` to the top of `\rule`.

A small difference with no `setstretch`:

[image: No <code>setstretch</code>]

And a bigger difference with `\setstretch{1.6}`:

[image: <code>\setstretch{1.6}</code>]

My aim is, to align the top of the X with the top of the image by a length variable, to be independent from different line spaces.

**Edit:**
Unfortunately, I forget one command in my MWE.
I add the line `\renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\tiny}` because I would like to have a solution which is independent of the size of the chosen fontsize in marginnote.
I tried to get the correct length in `raise=` but I failed.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to explain the entire story as it is late night, but here is an option using `adjustbox` macros. We define the macro:

```
\newcommand{\marginfig}[2][scale=0.1]{%
    \includegraphics[#1,valign=T,raise=\fontcharht\font`X]{#2}
    }
```

and use it like:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% load packages
\usepackage{blindtext, setspace}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[fulladjust]{marginnote}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\marginfig}[2][scale=0.1]{%
    \includegraphics[#1,valign=T,raise=\fontcharht\font`X]{#2}
    }

\begin{document}
\raggedleft

\blindtext

\marginnote{\marginfig[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}
X

\blindtext

\clearpage
\setstretch{1.8}

\blindtext

\marginnote{\marginfig{example-image}}
X

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Here we level the top of the image with the baseline of `X` and then `raise` it by the height of `X`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That look good! Unfortunately, I changed the size of the font in marginnote by `\renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\tiny}`. In this case, the box is not raised enough. Do you have an idea for this case? I extend my question with this command.

Comment: Because you are raising the box by ``\fontcharht\font`\X`` in the `\tiny` size. If you put in the preamble ``\newlength\marginraise \begingroup\normalfont\normalsize\selectfont \global\setlength\marginraise{\fontcharht\font`\X} \endgroup`` and then change the macro to `raise=\marginraise`, I think it should work.

Comment: I tried something similar. Unfortunately, the font selection of `\normalfont` does not work. Both images are not aligned properly. Do you know why? I think, `raise=` does not react on the variable. I assigned a fixed value to `\marginraise` and nothing happens.

Comment: After trying around some time, I switched the order and put the marginnote inside the adjustbox. Then everything works fine: `\newcommand*{\mymarginpic}[1]{\adjustbox{valign=T, raise=\fontcharht\font'X}{\marginnote{\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{#1}}}}`

Comment: I'm not sure, does the swap make sense?